# relationship between two set of variable

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

i am trying to determine what kind of  mathematical modeling could be  applied  following  two variables,let us call them $x$ and $y$  ,namely change one variable has effect  second on,i have several variants to clarify more  situation,let us introduce first $x$ variable

```
X =

    12
    43
    36
    98
```

and corresponding $y$

```
3658.16054016237
3615.00868922681
1599.25625005297
1599.02933228482
1339.16619762869
1339.14816547966
443.146645689262
443.056409980496
```

let  this be first pair,but please  note that $y$ is complex pair,which means that   in $y$  one pair corresponds  complex number,that why we have $4$ variable in $x$ and $8$ in $y$,second pair we have

X1

```
44
43
36
98
```

and

$Y1$

```
3658.19707577357
3615.01045850880
1634.39730289734
1630.86825150938
1597.96549473147
1594.19883425116
1339.00595993825
1338.65395128803
```

for more clarification i have consideration one more test
 third  $x$ variable

```
9   11  21  78
```

and corresponding output

```
2912.15233723249
2877.56286664859
783.071088238042
783.036270917237
412.991992321979
413.185665961216
332.019809596029
331.961759607682
```

there of course large pair corresponds largest in   $x$,second largest second biggest element in $x$ and so on,i think that it should polynomial order or exponential,but i think that polynomial order fitting would not be more help full,so something exponential should be in damped form,or damped exponential form should corresponds to each other,so please help me

Comment: This whole area is called curve fitting. You might start by plotting your data on linear-linear, linear-log, log-linear, or log-log scales. If one turns out (roughly) a straight line, your model isn't far.

Comment: is there any analytically method to   find solution?